# RESTful API with Java Jersey and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jersey

I am newbie with RESTful services, I am trying to make a restful api with the Jersey framework and MongoDB, my question is : How can i search data in the URL.

e.g : "localhost:9999/home/users/find?id=12345", it will return the user with the id = 12345

How can we do that with Jersey ?

Thank's

Comment: What part of this are you having problems with? How to write the Jersey code? How to write the Mongo access code? For the former, this is baisc stuff. Any good tutorial should provide an example using `@QueryParam`, which is what you need. If its the latter, take a look at [Getting Started with the Java Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver). And here's the [Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/). I suggest you make an attempt, then come back with a more concrete question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into @PathParam and @QueryParam. You can find more about both of them here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5np/index.html

In short, a path param is the bit between the '/', in your example this is "find". and the query param is id, which has a value of 12345.

You will then need to look this up in a database I assume to get your result to return.

Comment: Just to clarify, the bit between the "/"'s doesn't have to be a `@PathParam`. It could simply just be a part of the `@Path` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at an article I wrote a few years ago. I have a full stack MongoDb, Jersey, Jetty server user admin application at the following github [here](https://github.com/pmkent/angular-bootstrap-java-rest"Angular Bootstrap Java Rest")!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When referring to external links, please copy all relevant parts to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use a [query parameter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2286) in Jersey, you'll define it in the jersey Method signature like so:

```
@GET
@Path("home/users/find")
public Response myMethod(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
  // utilizes the id specified in the url parameter "id"
  User user = someMongoMethodToFindById(id);
}
```

Once you harvest the id correctly, you can then query your MongoDB however you'd like based on that passed-by-reference `id`.

In Jersey, this method is often wrapped in a class in which all related Jersey Resources can be organized. My examples given utilize the Jersey Annotation style.

```
@Path("home/users")
public class UserResources {

  @Path("find")
  public Response myMethod(@QueryParam("id")) {
  ...  
  }

}
```